# Custom defining cite command to include three authors and more than that et al

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am wondering if I can build a custom cite command that I would only use for one paper I cite where I would like to have the third author shown as well but only for that paper.

I am using a constructed custom command

```
\newcommand\mycite[1]{% with Numbers 
\citeauthor{#1}~(\citeyear{#1})\@
}
```

Can someone help me modify this one?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use `natbib`, you get cite commands like the one you are looking for:

http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php

You can use e.g. `\citet*{jon90}` for that. If you do not like the round brackets for citing, you can customize that (and a lot more).